# How can I install Oracle ASM on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install Oracle ASM on Ubuntu but I couldn't find ubuntu packages for ASM. Is there any way to install Oracle ASM on Ubuntu?

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://serverfault.com/ which is a site dedicated to systems administration

Comment: Generally Oracle supports their software on Red Hat (and it's clones).

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the instructions here :

http://www.pythian.com/news/810/howto-set-up-oracle-asm-on-ubuntu-gutsy-gibbon/